# Measuring AC current with Raspberry Pi Pico

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, adc, offset

I need to measure the voltage from a current transformer with a Raspberry Pi Pico, but it outputs both positive and negative voltages, so I need to offset it.

Can anyone recommend me a simple op-amp circuit that can do that? The only power supply that I have available is the Pico's power.

Comment: You don't need an op-amp to produce an offset.

Comment: Do you need to actually sample the positive and negative parts of the signal? Or you need to know the overall amplitude? In the latter case you could just use a diode bridge to convert your AC to DC and a shunt resistor across which you'll measure the voltage.